# python configparser to parse the data saved in a text file

Tags: python, file-io, configparser

I have a text file called sampl1.txt. This is what is inside this text file:-

```
111
112
113
114
115
```

I have a .ini file called config_num.ini which contains:-

```
[num_group]
file = sample1.txt
```

Here is the code snippet:-

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config_num.ini')
sample = config.get('num_group','file')
print sample
```

Is there any way to parse this so that when I read this 'file' and try to print it, it prints the elements which are in the txt file? Right now it prints sample1.txt. I want the numbers to printed.

Comment: does the content of config_num.ini stay the same?

Comment: yes the content stays the same in .ini file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost answered the question in itself!

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config_num.ini')
sample = config.get('num_group','file')
sample = open(sample, 'r').read()
print sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd have to override your ConfigParser, but I'd advise only loading the file when you call get

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    def get(self, section, option, **kwargs):
        ret = super(MyConfigParser, self).get(section, option, **kwargs)

        if option == "file":
            try:
                return open(ret, 'r').read()
            except IOError:
                pass

        return ret
```

Then you can create your new ConfigParser

```
cfg = MyConfigParser()
cfg.read('config_num.ini')
print cfg.get('num_group', 'file')
```